# Shape of passed values error when using apply on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to apply a basic spline function on all rows of a given dataframe (dfTest, which contains values for vector x) to obtain a bigger one (dfBigger) that would contain all values for vector xnew(which contains x).

I therefore define the following variables:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,3,5]
xnew = range(0,6)

np.random.seed(123)
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12).reshape(3,4))
```

and the basic spline function :

```
def spline(y, x , xnew):
    from scipy import interpolate
    model = interpolate.splrep(x,y, s=0.)
    ynew = interpolate.splev(xnew,model)
    result = ynew.round(3)
    return result
```

which seems to work:

```
spline(dfTest.iloc[0],x,xnew)
Out[176]: array([ 0.696,  0.286,  0.161,  0.227,  0.388,  0.551])
```

but when I try to apply it on all rows using :

```
dfBigger = dfTest.apply(lambda row : spline(row, x, xnew), axis = 1)
```

I got this :

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 6), indices imply (3, 4)
```

as dfBigger size is not defined anywhere I cannot see what is wrong. Any help and/or comment about this code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`df.apply(func)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) tries to build a new Series or DataFrame out of the values
returned by `func`. The shape of the Series or DataFrame depends on the kind of
value returned by `func`. To get a better handle on how `df.apply` behaves, 
experiment with the following calls:

```
dfTest.apply(lambda row: 1, axis=1)                       # Series
dfTest.apply(lambda row: [1], axis=1)                     # Series
dfTest.apply(lambda row: [1,2], axis=1)                   # Series
dfTest.apply(lambda row: [1,2,3], axis=1)                 # Series
dfTest.apply(lambda row: [1,2,3,4], axis=1)               # Series
dfTest.apply(lambda row: [1,2,3,4,5], axis=1)             # Series

dfTest.apply(lambda row: np.array([1]), axis=1)           # DataFrame
dfTest.apply(lambda row: np.array([1,2]), axis=1)         # ValueError
dfTest.apply(lambda row: np.array([1,2,3]), axis=1)       # ValueError
dfTest.apply(lambda row: np.array([1,2,3,4]), axis=1)     # DataFrame!
dfTest.apply(lambda row: np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), axis=1)   # ValueError

dfTest.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([1]), axis=1)          # DataFrame
dfTest.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([1,2]), axis=1)        # DataFrame
dfTest.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([1,2,3]), axis=1)      # DataFrame
dfTest.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([1,2,3,4]), axis=1)    # DataFrame
dfTest.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]), axis=1)  # DataFrame
```

So what rules can we draw from these experiments?

- If `func` returns a scalar or a list, `df.apply(func)` returns a Series.
- If `func` returns a Series, `df.apply(func)` returns a DataFrame.
- If `func` returns a 1D NumPy array, **and** the array has only one element, `df.apply(func)` returns a DataFrame. (not a terribly useful case...)
- If `func` returns a 1D NumPy array, **and** the array has the same number of elements as `df` has columns, `df.apply(func)` returns a DataFrame. (useful, but limited)

Since `func` returns 6 values, and you want a DataFrame as the result,
the solution is to have `func` return a Series instead of a NumPy array:

```
def spline(y, x, xnew):
    ...
    return pd.Series(result)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate

def spline(y, x, xnew):
    model = interpolate.splrep(x,y, s=0.)
    ynew = interpolate.splev(xnew,model)
    result = ynew.round(3)
    return pd.Series(result)

x = [0,1,3,5]
xnew = range(0,6)
np.random.seed(123)
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12).reshape(3,4))
# spline(dfTest.iloc[0],x,xnew)
dfBigger = dfTest.apply(lambda row : spline(row, x, xnew), axis=1)
print(dfBigger)
```

yields

```
        0      1      2      3      4      5
 0  0.696  0.286  0.161  0.227  0.388  0.551
 1  0.719  0.423  0.630  0.981  1.119  0.685
 2  0.481  0.392  0.333  0.343  0.462  0.729
```

Comment: Superb answer, thanks a lot. I really don't get the behaviour of the function when given numpy arrays... I will remember to try and convert to Series when getting a problem with pandas now.